# C++ like Map in Java?

Tags: java

Is there any way to access Java map like C++?

In C++, the following code snippet works:

```cpp
map<string, int> myMap;
string str = "okay";
myMap[str] = 69;
myMap[str]++;
cout<<myMap[str]<<endl;
```

the above code works perfectly and shows 70 in console.

Is there anything like that in Java?

Comment: There is a [Map interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) for Java

Comment: `myMap.get("key")` in Java works the same way as `myMap["key"]` in `C++`

Comment: If you mean something like "index"-access using brackets `[]`, then no, java doesn't have such a direct functionality

Comment: @Oo.oO: except it only works for reading the value, not for writing (which is what the line with `++` does). I think C++ calls that difference lvalue vs. rvalue, but I'm not 100% sure on that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes and no.

Yes, in that obviously you can get a similar result in Java code.

No, in that many of the C++ concepts you use don't have a direct equivalent in Java, so the Java code will look quite different.

## Basic example

On a trivial level the equivalent to `map<string,int>` is [`Map<String, Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html). Note that `int` can't be used here, since Java generics don't support primitive types as type arguments, so you'll need to use the wrapper. In code that difference will be mostly invisible, thanks to auto-boxing.

But `Map` is an interface, so you'll need to specify which implementation you want to use. [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html) is the default choice, if you have no specific requirements.

```
Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Java doesn't have (custom) operator overloading, so you'll need to call [`.put()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#put(K,V)) to add a value to the map:

```
String str = "okay";
myMap.put(str, 69); // nice
```

And due to the same issue and since `Integer` objects are immutable, the following line will look a bit uglier in Java:

```
myMap.put(str, myMap.get(str) + 1);
```

Printing is then simply this:

```
System.out.println(myMap.get(str));
```

## Alternative 1: Use `compute`

One alternative (that I personally find overkill) is to use the [`compute`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#compute(K,java.util.function.BiFunction)) method and a lambda expression like this (there's also [`computeIfPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfPresent(K,java.util.function.BiFunction)) and [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) with the obviuos restrictions):

```
myMap.compute(str, (k, v) -> v+1);
```

## Alternative 2: use `AtomicInteger` (or `int[]`) instead of `Integer`

Another alternative is to use something like [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) as your value. In this case you wouldn't really care about the fact that `AtomicInteger` has atomic operations, but use it as a "mutable `Integer`" in a way.

```
Map<String, AtomicInteger> myMap = new HashMap<>();
String str = "okay";
myMap.put(str, new AtomicInteger(69));
myMap.get(str).incrementAndGet();
```

Since `AtomicInteger` is mutable, you don't have to change the map to change what value it points to. Some people use a one-element array (like `new int[1]`) to get a similar effect. I'd consider both uses a bit hacky and personally prefer the more explicit `AtomicInteger`:

```
Map<String, int[]> myMap = new HashMap<>();
String str = "okay";
myMap.put(str, new int[] { 69 });
myMap.get(str)[0]++;
```

Comment: Thanks, this has been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using HashMap for this purpose if i am getting this correctly you want to use key value pair.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("okay", 10);
map.get("okay");
```

For more info you can check
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-hashmap-in-java-with-examples/